# nvidia in ubuntu, installed but not considered

Tags: ubuntu, artificial-intelligence, driver, nvidia

I have `GP108BM [GeForce MX250]` in my ASUS laptop.
I installed the drivers from "additional drivers" and run several commands.

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
Info: the nvidia profile is already set
```

However:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:148 memory:c2000000-c2ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP108BM [GeForce MX250]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c3000000-c3ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:c4000000-c407ffff
```

You can see in `configuration driver=i915 latency=0`.
And in about/settings:

[image]

[image]

My plan is to use it mainly for fastai and pytorch (AI) but in anything else too.
It's in my understanding that drivers are installed but the system is not acknowledging the nvidia GPU as primary. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think should ask here: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thank you shared in askubuntu as well!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, steps I followed are described in the forum below.

-purged nvidia drivers

-disabled secure boot

-installed again the drivers

-reboot

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/newly-installed-drivers-are-not-found-when-nvidia-smi-is-called/82686/7